# spring version set to 3.2.1.RELEASE in pom but different jar in project

Tags: java, spring, maven, dependency-management

In the pom file of a java project I have the spring dependencies set to version `3.2.1.RELEASE` but when I run a `mvn dependency:tree` I get different versions for some of the dependencies:

```
 org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.0.0.RC3:compile
 org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:compile
 org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.0.0.RC3:compile
 org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.0.0.RC3:compile
 org.springframework:spring-test:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:test
 com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-spring:jar:1.12:compile
 +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.0.0.RC3:compile
 |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
 \- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.0.0.RC3:compile
    \- org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.0.0.RC3:compile
```

The weird thing is that in other project which also depends on spring `3.2.1.RELEASE` I actually get the denendencies I declared in the pom file.

Any idea why this weird thing is happening? Could this be because of other dependencies I have?

EDIT:
here's the pom file

```
<!-- properties -->
<properties>
    <org.springframework.version>3.2.1.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    <com.jersey.version>1.17</com.jersey.version>
    <org.richfaces.version>4.1.0.Final</org.richfaces.version>
    <jsf.api.version>2.1.7</jsf.api.version>
    <powermock.version>1.5</powermock.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Jersey Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jersey -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        <version>${com.jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>${com.jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${com.jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>${com.jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>${com.jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSF -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jsf.api.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${jsf.api.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet, JSP, JSTL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Tomcat 6 need this -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Richfaces -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.richfaces.ui</groupId>
        <artifactId>richfaces-components-ui</artifactId>
        <version>${org.richfaces.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.richfaces.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>richfaces-core-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${org.richfaces.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Log4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- powermock -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>${powermock.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
        <version>${powermock.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-easymock</artifactId>
        <version>${powermock.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: Could we see the pom.xml file?

Comment: @blackpanther, just added the pom content.

Comment: Do you have a `<dependencyManagement>` section, maybe in a parent POM?

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser no, no <dependencyManagement> section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is quite likely that another library in your project has a dependency on 3.0.0.RC. My best guess is Jersey-Spring. Try excluding all the relevant spring dependencies from it like below and it should pick up your specified version.

`

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
<artifactId>jersey-spring</artifactId>
<version>1.12</version>
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
</exclusion>
.....
```

`

Comment: Maven resolves version conflicts by choosing the dependency that's nearer in the dependency graph. Hence `org.springframework:spring-core:3.2.1.RELEASE` should win over any transitive dependency.

Comment: @howiewylie I think you are right, I removed the jersey-spring dependency and the dependency tree now shows 3.2.1.RELEASE version for spring